# Left or right skewed prior in WinBUGS

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, bugs, inference

I am trying to find a proper way of defining a right or left skewed continuous (0...100) distribution for my priors in a simple linear regression.

Furthermore, I expect to find some outliers in my data (most concentrated on the right or left, but some very bad performers)

Do you know how may I specify this in WinBUGs?

Comment: You'd like to set a bounded continuous prior on regression coefficients, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. I was wondering whether I could set some skewed distributions somehow... I know I can use the I() function for truncating, but not how to skew the dnorm distribution...

Comment: A scaled beta distribution comes to mind, but I can't say how you'd specify that in WinBUGS.